# Getting the following error in PHP "PDOException - SQLSTATE[HY000] [1040] Too many connections "

Tags: php, mysql, nginx, mysql-5.6

We are using the Nginx web server with PHP and MySQL 5.6 Amazon RDS server.
While accessing a page of our app we are getting the following error.

PHP message:

> [1040] PDOException - SQLSTATE[HY000] [1040] Too many connections -" while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /manager/applications.php HTTP/1.0", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "

We have checked max_connections parameter in MySQL and its 600. We have only 2 active connections in our MySQL RDS server. And also we have enough RAM and hard disk space.